# scipy.interp2d [Segmentation fault (core dumped)]

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have a problem with the function scipy.interp2d. The example is very simple:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
import numpy as np

n=60   #Critical parameter

x = np.linspace(-10,10,n)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)
r = X**2+Y**2
plt.imshow(r)
plt.show()

f = interp2d(x,x,r)
new_x = np.linspace(-10,10,10)
plt.imshow(f(new_x,new_x))
plt.show()
```

If n=2,...,59, all is fine, but when n=60, segmentation fault appears. This is a scipy bug?

On the other hand, I did note that when the values of the function are hight and the domain is small, there are big problems with this function. I beleive that there are some internal problems with the implementation of this routine.

Any tip?

Scipy version: 0.11.0

Comment: Is there any problems when `n>60`?

Comment: n=61,62, 63 ok; n=64 --> Warning: No more knots can be added because the number of B-spline coefficients already exceeds the number of data points m. Probably causes: either s or m too small. (fp>s).
n=70, seg. fault.

Comment: I suspect it's a bug - I can reproduce this in scipy 0.11.0, but not in 0.13.0.dev-fe8b0a5

Answer (score 0):

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip uninstall scipy
pip install numpy --no-cache-dir
pip install scipy --no-cache-dir
```

This worked for me

Reason for crash - [Python Shared Libraries: RTLD_GLOBAL segfault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849755/python-shared-libraries-rtld-global-segfault/21096879#21096879)

Comment: I was getting segfaults with scipy's RBFInterpolator. This turned out to be the solution +1