# Loading C library in Python that dlopens another C library - unresolved shared symbol

Tags: python, c, linux, ctypes, dlopen

I have a commercial c library (a.so) that has several functions. When you call the a.open() function, it performs a dlopen() call for another library dynamically. If calling a.open('b'), it will open b.so. If calling a.open('c'), it will open c.so.

The problem is that a.so and b.so share a global variable defined in a.so, but referenced by b.so (and c.so,etc.). I am able to load a.so correctly in python using ctypes and see all the symbols in Python. However, when I call a.open('b'), it attempts to load b.so but returns undefined symbol.

```
//a.c -source for a.so library
int aglobal = 0;
void open(char* lib)
{ dlopen(lib); }

//b.c - source for b.so library
extern int aglobal;
```

Here is my python code to load:

```
from ctypes import cdll
p = ctypes.CDLL('a.so')
p.open('b')
```

returns the error code: undefined symbol: aglobal

Some other notes:

- files are linked with -fPIC -rdynamic -shared
- When I write a C program that does the same as the python program,
  there is not a problem.
- I've tried swig to wrap the library also, and numerous other things, build options, etc. but same results.

Is Python binding the symbols differently or something?

Comment: Good point - this is Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`RTLD_GLOBAL`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) when you load `a.so`.

> The object's symbols shall be made available for the relocation processing of any other object. In addition, symbol lookup using `dlopen(0, mode)` and an associated `dlsym()` allows objects loaded with this mode to be searched.

The [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) is a bit more straightforward:

> The symbols defined by this shared object will be made
>                 available for symbol resolution of subsequently loaded shared
>                 objects.

The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#loading-shared-libraries) describes the presence of the option but does not describe what it does.

> *New in version 2.6: The use_last_error and use_errno optional parameters were added.*
>
> `ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL`
>   Flag to use as mode parameter. On platforms where this flag is not available, it is defined as the integer zero.
>
> `ctypes.RTLD_LOCAL`
>   Flag to use as mode parameter. On platforms where this is not available, it is the same as `RTLD_GLOBAL`.
>
> `ctypes.DEFAULT_MODE`
>   The default mode which is used to load shared libraries. On OSX 10.3, this is `RTLD_GLOBAL`, otherwise it is the same as `RTLD_LOCAL`.

From the documentation, it appears you are on a system where `DEFAULT_MODE` is the same as `RTLD_LOCAL`, which is the converse of `RTLD_GLOBAL`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was simple enough for you! I also found that when I use my SWIG wrapped library that I can do this to get the imported library to dlopen b.so correctly. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849755/python-shared-libraries-rtld-global-segfault)

Comment: When using a scripting language to perform systems programming, remember that you will sometimes need to consult operating system reference material.